# binding an object graph with winforms

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-5

I want to know how many bindings I should have on a data entry form.

I have the following domain classes

```
public class SalesOrder  
{
     public virtual DocumentHeader DocumentHeader {get; set;}
     // some other properties   
}

public class DocumentHeader
{
  public virtual Account Account {get; set;}    
 // some other properties
}
```

The context has

```
 public DbSet<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
 public DbSet<DocumentHeader> DocumentHeaders { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

My data entry screen displays fields from the sales order and document header, and it displays the account.

I have the following code to set up the bindingsource

```
var dset = this.Context.SalesOrders;
 this.bindingSource.DataSource = dset.Local.ToBindingList();
```

How do I bind the DocumentHeader and Account properties on the data entry form?

Comment: winforms does not support deep property binding. You're looking for WPF.

Comment: there must be a work around... should I load the properties into some separate bindingsources on the main bindingSource_currentChanged event?